# INDEX+MATCH with arguments parsing

Tags: google-sheets

I have 2 tabs in my sheet. The first one contains the Code (number) and the value for it for each month.

The second one contains the list of codes separated by commas and the same months. How to receive the SUM of all codes specified in the list?

Here is the example -
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xTI09EhKrPRgEf4Lz1KnpMH44rwLaPLLuYfxrixuIk4/edit#gid=746719755

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try:*

```js
=map(A2:A,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,bycol(B1:1,lambda(Λ,if(Λ="",,sum(ifna(filter(filter(indirect("Sheet1!B2:"&rows(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!B1:1=Λ),regexmatch(Sheet1!A2:A&"","^"&substitute(Σ,",","$|^")&"$"))))))))))
```

[image]

***single cell formula (goes into `Cell_B2` of `Sheet2`)***

```js
=sum(ifna(filter(filter(indirect("Sheet1!B2:"&rows(Sheet1!$A:$A)),Sheet1!$B$1:$1=B$1),regexmatch(Sheet1!$A$2:$A&"","^"&substitute($A2,",","$|^")&"$"))))
```

Comment: It works. Can it be the separate formula for each cell instead of one for the array?

Comment: Updated the answer...